# Is there a size limit for kernel module in linux?

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel-module, vmalloc

I have a problem loading a kernel module, there is a large data structure, around the size of 2Gb of memory - whether I preallocate the table (so that it shows in .bss when I do `size -A module.ko` or try to `vmalloc()` it at load time, the module loading fails with `insmod: error inserting 'module.ko': -1 Cannot allocate memory`.

I tried debugging the problem on usermode linux, but I get a bunch of segfaults (that can be continued in gdb, but end up with a console message `overflow in relocation type 10 val <value in the ball park of 6G>` and `'module' likely not compiled with -mcmodel=kernel`. I assume that with `Kbuild` the `-mcmodel` should be right, right?

So the questions are:

1. Is there a generic 2G limit for linux kernel module size?
2. Is there a specific 2G limit for kernel modules in usernode linux (I *think* that in past I've noticed that a large kernel module needs a clean, continuous block of memory...)
3. Can I specify `-mcmodel=large` for a kernel module and expect it to work?

I've tried this on debian squeeze, 64-bit, 2.6.32-5-amd64 (host) with 8Gb of memory and 2.6.32 in uml with 4G memory, so this should **not** be an ordinary out of memory problem.

**Extra credit for working around the limit, if such limit exists :)**

Comment: 2GB code + data segments? You gotta be kidding! Can't you just `mmap` your data and not compile it in?

Comment: Unfortunately, I kid you not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I define the table as `static` - the module loading will indeed fail - this is probably because of the 1.5G limit mentioned in the answer by [Andrew Aylett](https://stackoverflow.com/users/24762/andrew-aylett)

However, if I do dynamic `vmalloc()` calls, I was able to get up to 7680Mb on a host with 8Gb of memory (until the kernel killed some crucial process and my X hanged).

So to answer my questions:

1. Yes, but only for data that is compiled in as `static`
2. Doesn't look like it.
3. There is no need to do that.

Extra credit: just do `vmalloc()`

This only works in linux kernels **newer than 2.6.10** - before that, the `vmalloc()` [limit was 64 Mb.](http://lists.netfilter.org/pipermail/netfilter-devel/2005-February/018405.html)

Answer (score 8):

As for your first question - the limit on the module itself is 64 megabytes. The module loader will reject to load a module that exceeds this size. From [kernel/module.c](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/kernel/module.c?v=2.6.32#L2117):

```
if (len > 64 * 1024 * 1024 || (hdr = vmalloc(len)) == NULL)
        return ERR_PTR(-ENOMEM);
```

This is true both for 2.6.32 and for the newer kernels too, up to 3.3.

EDIT: In kernel version 3.4, the 64 Mb limit [was removed](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/kernel/module.c?id=f946eeb9313ff1470758e171a60fe7438a2ded3f). Now the actual limit depends only on how much memory `vmalloc()` can allocate.

Answer (score 1):

Remember that kernel-space memory is different from user-space memory -- on 32-bit Linux, the kernel has only 1Gb address space.  There's a log more space address space for the kernel on 64-bit Linux, but [kernel documentation](http://www.mjmwired.net/kernel/Documentation/x86/x86_64/mm.txt) suggests that only 1536MB is available for modules.

Comment: On 64-bit, there is essentially no address space limit (well, the limit is many TB).

Comment: As for x86-64, probably this brief description of memory areas in the kernel space may help: [Documentation/x86/x86_64/mm.txt](http://www.mjmwired.net/kernel/Documentation/x86/x86_64/mm.txt). The upper limits can be deduced from there, although the actual limits can be lower of course.

Comment: If I do a dynamic `vmalloc()`, it seems I can get as much memory as I want (and is available) - see my test code at http://paste.pocoo.org/show/406020/